# How can I wait for Async(geocodeService.GeocodeAsync) service/method to complete?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, async-await

Am using the **GeocodeService** to get the `lattitude` and `longitude` of two places( from, to)

am getting latitude and longitude perfectly but my problem is the message is displaying before **async** call (`geocodeService.GeocodeAsync`) how can i wait to complete Async call (`geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted` ) ??

my code is

```
private void point_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getCoordinates(fromText.Text, 1);// this is calling after bellow message box :(
    getCoordinates(toText.Text, 2);
    MessageBox.Show(" completed ");  // 1 why this message is displaying first before above calls      
}

private void getCoordinates(string address, int index)
    {
        GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest();

        // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        geocodeRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
        geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = "ApgLkoHIG4rNShRJAxMMNettsv6SWs3eP8OchozFS89Vex7BRHsSbCr31HkvYK-d";

        // Set the full address query
        geocodeRequest.Query = address;

        // Set the options to only return high confidence results 
        FilterBase[] filters = new FilterBase[1];
        filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter() { MinimumConfidence = Confidence.High };

        GeocodeOptions geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions();
        geocodeOptions.Filters = new ObservableCollection<FilterBase>(filters);
        geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

        // Make the geocode request
        GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
        geocodeService.GeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<GeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted);
        geocodeService.GeocodeAsync(geocodeRequest, index);

    }
    void geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted(object sender, GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = e.Result;
            fromLat = geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude;
            fromLon = geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude;
            Messagebox.Show("latitude : "+fromLat); // this is displaying randomly 
    }
```

Comment: You can't actually use `async`-`await` from C# 5.0 on WP7, no?

Comment: how can i achieve this ?? why my code not fallowing order of method calls ( in poini_click event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another method that activates a timer when the async completed is loaded.

pass it the e.result

Have the timer.tick check to see if e.result is length > 0

If it is on tick show window

else show loading or what ever

Something like this

```
#pretend code#
Global Variable -> string location;

getGeoLoc += new geoLocCompleted;

void geoLocCompleted(sender, e){
   location = e.result
   Timer time = new Timer():
   time.tick += OnTick;
```

}

```
void onTick(send, e){
   if(e.result.length > 0)
      Show your results
   else
      Show loading dialog
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but `geocodeService.GeocodeAsync` with out this call its not calling `eocodeCompleted` method